# Run a compiled C program on a computer where the headers don't exist

Tags: c++, c, compilation, execute

I have written a code which includes the Windows.h header, and compiled it using Visual Studio.

I have then tried to run the EXE file alone on my other computer, which appears to lack the specified header.

How can I run it on the other computer without having to install VS?

Comment: The headers aren't a problem, you need to package your DLLs. Or compile your program statically.

Comment: What was the error you encountered on the other PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executable file does not need header. It needs for dynamic libraries. They are distrubuted with Visual Studio or with Visual Studio Redistributable Package. You can distribute your program with that package. Another option - using static linking. With static linking executable will have all needed data and code.

Comment: What does static linking mean?

Comment: @w2a You can read about linking and difference between dynamic and static linking [here](http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-linking.php)